# Dynamical web pages with sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to build a dynamic web page with changing controls using an SQL database.
I can't insert in to a sql per control cause that doesn't add up on the SQL tables since I also need the tables and divs. Basically I tried to copy the whole html and putting it in a row but that doesn't seem to work and I can't get it out as pure text. Maybe some suggestions for this?

I am looking in to any Object SQL so I can just insert the whole form as bytes or any other way.
Is there any library for OSQL on C#?(I want to do this server side) Or any tips on how to do this properly?

I was trying to insert the HTML code to SQL for future use but this gave me errors

```
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    Form1.RenderControl(w);
    string s = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
 string command = "INSERT INTO `htmltables`(`Company`, `Type`, `HTML`) VALUES  ('TestCompany','TestType','" + s + "')";
```

In any case I'd really want to insert Objects instead of pure HTML cause this will ease my work in the future.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of dotNet are you using? When you say it doesn't seem to work, what do you mean? Does a select statement in SQL bring back the HTML? What datatype are you using?

Comment: Also, show your code, even if you have given up it may be something simple that you have overlooked..

Comment: Well first of all I am trying to insert the page in to SQL so I just tried to use InnerHtml on a form. It gave me an error and I just said I should try some different approach. In anycase I'd like to consider inserting objects to SQL instead of pure html. I'll edit the question to show some code.

Comment: Have you considered making the class serialisable? That way you don't need to store the HTML. You should use an XML dataype in the database if you do this, rather than a string.

Comment: Yes! Thats it. Its something I was looking for and forgot all about it. Thank you so much! Serialization is the anwser.

Comment: I've posted an example for serialising objects

Comment: you could try converting the HTML to base64 string and then inserting it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try to fix your query:

```
"INSERT INTO `htmltables`(`Company`, `Type`, `HTML`) VALUES 
('TestCompany','TestType','" + s + "')"
```

1. Try to remove the characters from the string.

   `"INSERT INTO htmltables(Company, Type, HTML) VALUES ('TestCompany','TestType','" + s + 
   "')"`
2. and try using Parameters such as:

   `"INSERT INTO htmltables(Company, Type, HTML) VALUES (@0,@1,@2)", "The Company", "TestType", s`

And make the query up.

For me there is only this error.

#### Adding the divs to the database

This is isn't an issue, the issue might be that the server isn't allowing such characters thinking they might be potential. For this you can try this:

```
Request.Unvalidated["name"];
```

This way, the server would get the `div` or any other HTML markup being inserted.

> Basically I tried to copy the whole html and putting it in a row but that doesn't seem to work and I can't get it out as pure text.

It should work when you will use the term I suggested, but wait, you're saying it doesn't seem to work so how can you get the text? Nothing would be provided unless there is some data. Your question is a bit confusing. Sorry for this.

#### Reference:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012(v=sql.80).aspx

MSDN would be your best buddy in this issue! :)

Comment: I was more fishing for suggestions for different approaches to be honest than an anwser for the query(I know I am confusing I am sorry) but your anwser was helpful with the Unvalidated part. I rather think I should close this question for now gather my data and try again later.

Comment: You can explain your question well :) We will help you out

Answer (score 0):

Your html text may include improper characters for Sql. Safest way is to use parameters.

For Example:

```
        string connectionString = "";
        string html = "<div id=\'loremIpsum\'><div/>";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlConnection(connectionString).CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "insert into YourTable (YourColumn) values(@yourParameter)";
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("yourParameter", html));
            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Additioanlly I am not sure for what purpose you want to keep htmls in sql database but you can use a nosql database instead. Because I'm assuming you will have lots of data and nosql databases are more appropriate for such data..

Comment: Instead of a nosql I just create Text Files instead of rows. But I guess its a similar concept as to nosql. The problem for me now is that after I try to get the html for the pages the asp controls themselves which don't automatically get translated to client side code. Well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Serialise your class and put the xml object in the database, here is an example of a serialised class and functions for serialisation to and from the object/xml:

**VB.net**

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Namespace NamespaceGoesHere
    <DataContract()> _
    Public Class ClassNameGoesHere
        'All your properties go here, for example:
        <DataMember> Property PropertyName As String = "test"
        'Note the use of <DataMember> and <DataContract()>

        #Region "Serialisation"
            Public Function Serialise() As String
                Dim s As New System.IO.MemoryStream
                Dim x As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(ClassNameGoesHere))

                x.WriteObject(s, Me)
                s.Position = 0

                Dim sw As New StreamReader(s)
                Dim str As String

                str = sw.ReadToEnd()

                Return str
            End Function

            Public Shared Function DeSerialise(xmlDocument As String) As ClassNameGoesHere
                Dim doc As New XmlDocument
                Dim ser As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(ClassNameGoesHere))

                Dim stringWriter As New StringWriter()
                Dim xmlWriter As New XmlTextWriter(stringWriter)

                doc.LoadXml(xmlDocument)
                doc.WriteTo(xmlWriter)

                Dim stream As New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringWriter.ToString()))
                stream.Position = 0
                Dim reader As XmlDictionaryReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream, New XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas())

                Return DirectCast(ser.ReadObject(reader, True), ClassNameGoesHere)
            End Function
        #End Region
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace NamespaceGoesHere
{
    [DataContract()]
    public class ClassNameGoesHere
    {
        //All your properties go here, for example:
        [DataMember()]
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        //Note the use of [DataMember()] and [DataContract()]

        #region "Serialisation"
        public string Serialise()
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream s = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            DataContractSerializer x = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ClassNameGoesHere));

            x.WriteObject(s, this);
            s.Position = 0;

            StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(s);
            string str = null;

            str = sw.ReadToEnd();

            return str;
        }

        public static ClassNameGoesHere DeSerialise(string xmlDocument)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ClassNameGoesHere));

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

            doc.LoadXml(xmlDocument);
            doc.WriteTo(xmlWriter);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringWriter.ToString()));
            stream.Position = 0;
            XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());

            return (ClassNameGoesHere)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Once you have created your class you can serialise it into an xml string using the serialise function. Store this in the database (I would use an XML datatype but you can store it as NVARCHAR(MAX).
When returning from the database simply call the deserialise function passing in the string and you'll get your object back again.